# Distributed Load Testing for Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, automation, performance-testing, load-testing, agent

I have a load test set up that hits a website which will be the SUT.  I'm able to run this as expected with single user loads and very small loads (i.e. about 5 or less).  The issues I run in to are when I try to do larger loads such as 250+.  I'm noticing some bottlenecks and have read about the causes which leads me to this question.

To my understanding (which makes sense logically) I need to set up Controllers, Agents, Machines, etc in order to distribute the load and essentially spread this out to reduce the bottlenecking.

I have not found or figured out how to successfully accomplish this in order to throw large loads at the SUT and record the results accurately.

Is this possible to do with Visual Studio 2015 as of the current date of writing this.  The resources I have found seem to be dated and simply state Controllers/Agents are deprecated/unsupported with VS15.

Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: A simple web search provides the answer. Look at https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/test/lab-management/test-machines/install-configure-test-agents

Comment: I've looked at this.  Anything for 2013 is outdated and links no longer work.  So my only option seems to be hitting this from a build perspective.  If that's the case then I guess my revised question is what would the build definitions look like.  As in how do you create machines/agents from within the build.  I've explored this and am still clueless.  It wasn't much about not wanting to look, but rather a user-explained answer.

Comment: The page I cited was updated on 27 April this year, so only 5 weeks ago. The page discusses agents for VS-2015, and more. If the links are not working on a Microsoft page then grumble at Microsoft.

Comment: The ideas in the question are correct. Your can use agents to spread the genaration of the load. For VS-2015 they changed the role of the controller, merging it into Visual Studio and also into TFS. Hence for VS-2015 there is only an agent software. The older VS-2013 controller-and-agent software should still work (if you can find it).

Comment: I wasn't grumbling at you :P I'm just stating that if you're looking for, let's say Agents for 2013 update 5, that link no longer exists.  I know the ideas are right and I have this down conceptually, I'm just struggling to put it in place.  Thanks for your insight so far.  I think my route is going to be through TFS and have a some type of agent deployed, but i'm not positive how to set up the machines and agents to do the tasks.